# Javascript print function produce script inside of div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, printing

I have a function to print:

```
<script language="javascript">
function printdiv(printpage) {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
```

In my cshtml file:

```
<button type="button" onClick="printdiv('div_print');">Print</button>

<div id="div_print">@Html.ActionLink("Test","Nil","Nil")</div>
```

When I click the button Print, this comes out.

```
Test (/Nil/Nil)
```

I want it to just print

`Test`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you want to print part of page and then return the page again .
use MEDIA PRINT in CSS to hide and show elements in print, it's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This happens when you have proper href in anchor tag. If we set this to # it will work.

```
<script language="javascript">
function printdiv(printpage) {
    var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
    var footstr = "</body>";
    document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].setAttribute("href","#")
    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using this javascript code instead. It works.

```
 function printdiv(elem) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
```